# Best Web UI development framework for Jersey Web services

Tags: user-interface, web, jersey

I have developed a set of Web services in Jersey which I am now accessing through  a Jersey client application. However I would also like to have a Web UI for human users to access the Web services. Some of the interfaces will also need to use Google maps. I would like some advice on which is the best framework to use with Jersey for building these Web UIs that can get me quickly up and running. Preferably I would like to use template based solutions for generating HTML pages if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Jersey comes with a [simple MVC](https://blogs.oracle.com/sandoz/entry/mvcj) framework built-in. It has built in support for JSPs which you could leverage...